# Pasar comillas ' en un CALL o pasar la sentencia WHERE

Tags: mysql

Estoy haciendo un procedimiento en el que le pase como parametro el WHERE en una consulta.
Estoy teniendo problemas con las comillas al pasar el CALL 
Como puedo hacer para pasar esto `WHERE CAMPO2 = 'ROJO'` o `WHERE CAMPO2 = 'ROJO' and CAMPO3 = 'BAJO'`

```
CALL `consulta`('CAMPO2 = \'ROJO\'')


CREATE PROCEDURE `consulta`(IN `condicion` VARCHAR(250))
BEGIN 

SET @codi = condicion; 


 SET @sql_text1 = concat('SELECT COLUMNA1 FROM TB_PRUEBA', 'WHERE ', @codi );  

 PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_text1; 

 EXECUTE stmt1 ; 

 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 

END
```

Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si funciona como otras bases de datos podes intercambiar comillas dobles para definir la cadena y usar comillas simples adentro, pero no estoy nada seguro en mysql...

Comment: No entiendo, disculpa. El problema es al hacer el CALL desde algún código? O el procedimiento tiene algúñ problema?

Comment: @gbianchi no ha funcionado las " CALL `consulta`('CAMPO2 = "'ROJO"''). /* Error de SQL (1064) en la declaración #2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= "ROJO"' at line 1 */

Comment: @Alfabravo     El CALL lo estoy haciendo desde la consola de mysql.

Comment: No es necesario que uses concat intenta unicamente de la forma normal osea como concatenarias un string en sql.

Answer (score 1):

Funciona si se usan los delimitadores del procedimiento. Me tomé la libertad de añadir un [handler de excepción](https://medium.com/startupward/how-to-try-and-catch-errors-in-mysql-stored-procedures-56604ffa17df) para saber si fallaba algo dentro del procedimiento. Escaparlo como lo estás haciendo [funciona](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5462b47425d8b8b1ec74fc36b2fecc2e) bien siempre y cuando termines correctamente el procedimiento (`END;`). Si no añades el delimitador (`;`) para el último END, no va a saber que terminaste de declarar el procedimiento.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `consulta`(IN `condicion` VARCHAR(250))
BEGIN
 DECLARE exit handler for SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
  GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
   @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
  SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);
  SELECT @full_error;
  END;

SET @codi = condicion;
SET @sql_text1 = concat('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE ', @codi);  
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_text1; 
EXECUTE stmt1 ; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 
END;


CALL consulta(' \'1\' = \'1\'');
```

Comment: Es lo correcto \' tenia mal la sentencia el WHERE, se juntaba con el nombre de la tabla le faltaba un espacio. Gracias

Comment: Procura siempre añadir algún tipo de manejo de excepciones a tus procedimientos SQL. Suele ayudar a hacerles debug.